# Error in Calling Custom Function Inside NSManagedObject Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have created a function saveCategories(:)

[image]

I want to call it from another class:

[image]

But I'm receiving an error:

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on
>   NSManagedObject class 'BGMCategories'

May I know how could I call the function inside NSManagedObject subclass properly?

Comment: You should  add code instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

```
BGMCategories()
```

You cannot initialize an NSManagedObject subclass like this. It should be initialized like

```
let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BGMCategories", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! BGMCategories
```

Then use the object.

If need to add code for saving data int the class itself try adding a class method

Comment: I'm using AlecrimCoreData, may I know how could I get the managedObjectContext from it?

Comment: I am not familiar with AlecrimCoreData. Also if you create entity with insertNewObjectForEntity... it will add one record in the db. So please keep this in mind..